# Show that if $r,s \in E$, then $[r,s] \subset E$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:X \to C$ be measurable, $||f||_{\infty} > 0$, and let $\phi(p)= \int_X|f|^pd\mu$, and let
$$E=\{p \in (0,\infty): \phi(p) < \infty\}$$
I would like to show that if $r,s \in E$, then $[r,s] \subset E$. I am lost on what to prove for this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let $F=\{x\in X:|f|\leq 1\}$. Let $r,s\in E$. We first prove the case when $r\geq 1$. Since $r,s\in E$, then
\begin{align*}
\phi(r)&=\int_{X}|f|^{r}\,d\mu<\infty
\\
\phi(s)&=\int_{X}|f|^{s}\,d\mu<\infty
\end{align*}
and assume also $1\leq r<s$ (since if $r=s$, the result is true trivially). Then for any $t\in[r,s]$,
\begin{align*}
\phi(t)&=\int_{X}|f|^{t}\,d\mu
\\
&=\int_{F}|f|^{t}\,d\mu+\int_{X\setminus F}|f|^{t}\,d\mu
\\
&\leq\int_{F}|f|^{r}\,d\mu+\int_{X\setminus F}|f|^{s}\,d\mu
\\
&\leq\int_{X}|f|^{r}\,d\mu+\int_{X}|f|^{s}\,d\mu
\\
&<\infty
\end{align*}
which shows that $[r,s]\in E$.

For the case when $r<1$ and $s>1$, you can use a similar approach by considering $t\in[r,1]$ and $t\in[1,s]$, using the above argument when $t\in[1,s]$.

Any comments to improve or shorten the proof is welcome.